# Path tracing: how to ensure the new direction vector is a valid direction vector with respect to a BSDF?

Tags: c++, math, 3d, rendering, raytracing

Given the BSDF function and the `Normal` vector of the intersection point **in world space**, how can I generate a new direction vector `wi` that is valid? Does the method for generating valid `wi`s change based on the BSDF?

Here's an example of what I'm thinking to do for ideal diffuse material the BSDF: I generate a new direction vector `wi` as points on a unit hemisphere as follow and then compute the `dot` product of the produced vector with the `Normal` vector. If the `dot` product result is positive the direction vector `wi` is valid. Otherwise I negate `wi` as suggested [here](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/10622/path-tracing-how-to-ensure-we-are-sampling-a-direction-vector-within-the-visibl).

Here's how I get a random `wi`:

```
float theta = 2 * M_PI * uniform01(generator);
float phi = acos(uniform01(generator));
float x = sin(phi) * cos(theta);
float y = sin(phi) * sin(theta);
float z = cos(phi);
Vector3f wi(x, y, z);

if (dot(wi, Normal) > 0){
    return wi;
}
else{
    return -wi;
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to be the right approach based on a conversation I had with someone recently. Apparently the new direction vector produced this way is somehow not in the right space (not sure whether it was world or object space) and could only work if my material is ideal diffuse. So I will have to apply some transformations in order to be able to get the right `wi`. Is this correct? If so, can someone provide a solution that includes doing such transformation? Also, is there a general way to ensure all of my produced `wi`s are valid with respect to the BSDF (not just ideal diffuse)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating your `wi` in tangent space, with `z` pointing along the normal. It is neither world nor object space, and you will have to transform into world space or do all your calculations in tangent space (or shading space, they're both the same).

What you should be doing, as it will make your life much easier when doing other calculations, is to transform your `wo` to tangent space, and do all calculations in it. Over here, you would choose `z` to be your normal, and generate `x` and `y` vectors orthogonal to it.

A function for generating the coordinate system like this would be:

```
void GenerateCoordinateSystem(const Vector& normalized, Vector& outFirst, Vector& outSecond)
{
    if (std::abs(normalized.x) > std::abs(normalized.y))
    {
        outFirst = Vector(-normalized.z, 0, normalized.x) /
            std::sqrt(normalized.x * normalized.x + normalized.z * normalized.z);
    }
    else
    {
        outFirst = Vector(0, normalized.z, -normalized.y) /
            std::sqrt(normalized.z * normalized.z + normalized.y * normalized.y);
    }
    outSecond = Cross(normalized, outFirst);
}
```

Where `normalized` is the normal (`z` vector) at the point, and `outFirst` and `outSecond` are your `x` and `y` vectors respectively.

Now that you have your tangent space vectors, you transform into them by (`wo` is in object space):

```
Vector x, y;
GenerateCoordinateSystem(normal, x, y);
Vector tangentWo = Vector(Dot(wo, x), Dot(wo, y), Dot(wo, normal));
```

You would then generate your `wi` as you do above.
Then, to get `wi` in object space, you would:

```
Vector objWi = wi.X * x + wi.Y * y + wi.Z * normal;
```

If you want them in world space, you would obviously have to multiply them by the object's transformation matrix.

Uniform hemisphere sampling does ensure that your `wi` is valid for any BSDF, however, you  have to ensure that the `pdf` for the BSDF takes into account the distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the through response. I still have some confusion though probably because I expected a much simpler response. You said "You are generating your `wi` in tangent space, with `z` pointing along the normal". By `z` do you mean the `z` element of  the Normal vector`? Then you said "you would choose `z` to be your normal". Again, does this mean that the `z` element of the new coordinate system? Finally, you create the vector `tangentWo` but I don't see you using it afterwards. What's the purpose of creating `tangentWo`?

Comment: Also note that the Normal vector I have is already in world space. So how can objWi is in object space if we never transform the Normal vector to the object Normal?

Comment: @Amir By "You are generating your `wi` in tangent space, with `z` pointing along the normal" I meant that the `z` component of the `wi` you generated lies along the Normal vector. Yes, I meant the `z` component of the new, tangent space coordinate system. The purpose for `tangentWo` is the `wo` vector in tangent space, which you would then use for your lighting calculations. And oops, I thought the normal was in object space, so you should keep the normal in object space, or transform everything to world coordinates.